# NOT EQUAL IN SQL WONT WORK

Tags: mysql

I had a problem in my query

I WANTED my club name which is the "Default Club" wont display. but when I try it using not equal, it doesn't work. The "Default Club" still there.

And also the Number of students is wrong. But when I remove the `club.c_name <> 'Default Club'` , the number of students is correct.

Below is my query

```
SELECT DISTINCT club.c_name, c_description, count(s_id) as 'Number of Students' 
FROM club
left join student on club.c_name=student.c_name and club.c_name <> 'Default Club'
group by c_name;
```

Comment: *"But when I remove the "club.c_name <> 'Default Club'" , the number of students is correct."* - that's because you left out the `WHERE` clause. `WHERE club.c_name <> 'Default Club'`

Comment: oooh... why wont it accepts ON?? i thought when you use join you'll change WHERE to ON.. anyways, thank you! It Works ! :D

Comment: You're welcome. However someone posted an answer "after" I posted my comment, so not sure what you want me to do here. Post my comment as an answer? and no, that's not how the ON works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your original query, with appropriate spacing:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT club.c_name,
  c_description,
  count(s_id) as 'Number of Students' 
FROM
  club
LEFT JOIN student ON
  club.c_name=student.c_name AND
  club.c_name <> 'Default Club' 
GROUP BY
  c_name;
```

As can be seen from above, your JOIN criteria is `club.c_name = student.c_name`, AND `club.c_name <> 'Default Club'`.

What you are looking for is to use the JOIN criteria of only `club.c_name = student.c_name`. Once you get the result of JOIN, you filter out the records from 'Default Club' using WHERE clause.

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT club.c_name,
  c_description,
  count(s_id) as 'Number of Students' 
FROM
  club
LEFT JOIN student ON
  club.c_name=student.c_name 
WHERE
  club.c_name <> 'Default Club' 
GROUP BY
  c_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

*"But when I remove the "club.c_name <> 'Default Club'" , the number of students is correct."*

That's because you left out the `WHERE` clause.

This is what your query should read as:

```
on club.c_name=student.c_name WHERE club.c_name <> 'Default Club'
```

As per the manual:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

> *"The conditional_expr used with ON is any conditional expression of the form that can be used in a WHERE clause. Generally, you should use the ON clause for conditions that specify how to join tables, and the WHERE clause to restrict which rows you want in the result set."*

and

> *"If there is no matching row for the right table in the ON or USING part in a LEFT JOIN, a row with all columns set to NULL is used for the right table. You can use this fact to find rows in a table that have no counterpart in another table:"*

Example from the manual:

```
SELECT left_tbl.*
  FROM left_tbl LEFT JOIN right_tbl ON left_tbl.id = right_tbl.id
  WHERE right_tbl.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Tnx for explaining it further.. my net is being crazy lol thats why Im still commenting and I receive the replies late.. tnx anyway! sorry btw

Comment: @katkat sorry for *what?*